# JQuery click copy link to div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of countries and they all have an empty '#' anchor link.

I am stuck with telling JQuery to only "copy" one country to an empty div, but JQuery selects all '#' links inside the div.

Please see JS Fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/yb7MR/

and here is what I've done:

```
var country = $('a[href$="#"]').text();


$('a[href$="#"]').click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass("active");

  if ($('a').hasClass("active")) {

    $('div.location').prepend('<p>Your Location is: </p>');
    $('div.location').text(country);
    $(this).removeClass("active");

  } else {
    $('a[href$="#"]').removeClass("active");

    $('a[href$="#"]').not("active");

    // do nothing

  }

});
```

```
<body>
    <a href="#">France</a><br />
    <a href="#">Italy</a><br />
    <a href="#">Spain</a><br />
    <a href="#">Germany</a><br />

    <div class="location"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: your `event.preventDefault();` is completely useless if you don't use `.click(function ( event ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of the click on `.active` ones by using the
`.not()` selector

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLUNX/1/

```
$('a[href$="#"]').not('.active').click(function ( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('div.location').html('<p>Your Location is: '+ $(this).text() +'</p>');

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 2):

remove this line    `$('div.location').text(country);`

You can select text of clicked element using `$(this).text()`and set that text to div

Like this `$('div.location').text($(this).text());`

http://jsfiddle.net/viswa317/359Qq/

Comment: I don't know why someone upvoted your answer http://jsfiddle.net/359Qq/1/ cause you need to explain how you mean to handle the .active a bit more. Right now is inaccurate and also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the follwoing code.

```
$('a[href$="#"]').click(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    jQuery('a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    $('div.location').html('<p>Your Location is: </p>' + jQuery(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Why we need to use `jQuery(` ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently your setting the country variable to all the text values for each `<a>` tag with a href value of `#`. Also you might want to rethink your code, since your setting the class to `active` before the `if else` statement your `else` will never be called. One more issue with your current code is your `.prepend()` will be overridden by the `.text()`. With that said I have commented next to the issues and also put the country variable where it could go and showed you how to access the correct text value.

```
$('a[href$="#"]').click(function (event) {  
    event.preventDefault();     

    $(this).addClass("active"); //This will cause the else statement below to never do anything

    if ($('a').hasClass("active") ) {           
        $('div.location').prepend('<p>Your Location is: </p>'); //This will be overridden later by the .text()
        var country = $(this).text(); //Set the country variable here, using the current text value for the element that triggered this event
        $('div.location').text(country);
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else { //Because of the addClass above this will never do anything!
        $('a[href$="#"]').removeClass("active");

        $('a[href$="#"]').not("active");

        // do nothing

    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/yb7MR/3/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understand your question correctly. I think, you need to change

```
$('div.location').text(country);
```

to

```
$('div.location').text($(this).text());
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yb7MR/4/).

Comment: this is already answered by @Viswa why you think your answer is better?

Comment: i think his answer is much better

Comment: @roXon Yes. you are right. But he answered first with `$(this).html()`. I don't think `html()` is needed there, only `text()` is enough here.

Comment: @JustinJohn I just added a small CSS to your demo. can you explain what your demo actually does? http://jsfiddle.net/yb7MR/6/

Comment: @roXon This is OP question "I am stuck with telling JQuery to only "copy" one country to an empty div". From the OP's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/yb7MR/) I get feeling that all the countries are outputted at once instead of one. I just corrected it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned value to `var country` before `$('a[href$="#"]').click(function (event)` So It Get all links value. So assigned value to `var country` after click event and assign value `$(this).text()` So It will get that links value and add to div.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/RKAHR/

```
 $('a[href$="#"]').click(function (e) {
  var country = $(this).text();
  e.preventDefault();
  $('a[href$="#"]').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $('div.location').prepend('<p>Your Location is: </p>');
  $('div.location').text(country);
});
```

Comment: this is the most strange answer I ever seen. after you add a class of `active` how you expect the `else` to be called?

Comment: IF you don't understand. let's say you set a var to true, than just a line after you check for it's true or false. what's the answer?

Comment: take a look at my answer Jai

Comment: be honest, you did not sleep again :) Can you explain what's the `.prepend()` method for in your demo?

Comment: and yes Its morning time in India.

Comment: :) here is 8:00a.m. and I'm having my 6th coffee (exactly, without sleep. :) hello to India from Croatia!